# Insert command failed with return code SQLITE_ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database, when inserting data into the db,it always failed with return code SQLITE_ERROR

For example,the sqlite3_prepare_v2 always failed.

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into t_elementnode(opname,op,param) values('%@',%ld,'%@')",elementNode.name,elementNode.operation,elementNode.paramString];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
NSLog(@"====exit:%@,result:%d,op:%ld,param:%@",elementNode.name,result,elementNode.operation,elementNode.paramString);
return;
}

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, elementNode.name.UTF8String, -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 2, elementNode.operation);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, elementNode.paramString.UTF8String, -1, NULL);

result = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (result != SQLITE_DONE) {
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    NSLog(@"===insert error:%d",result);
    return;
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

the NSLog Output were:

====exit:title,result:1,op:11,param:{
  "locatorType" : 6,
  "locatorValue" : "//XCUIElementTypeLink[@name='title']"
}

Comment: Call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: I have tried call sqlite3_errmsg(), but no error msg

Comment: Show the code .

Comment: errmsg: resultCode:1

Comment: Show the Objective-C code that calls `sqlite3_errmsg()`.

Comment: char *errmsg = NULL;
    int result2 = sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    if (result2 != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"errmsg:%s resultCode:%d",errmsg,result2);
    }
    sqlite3_free(errmsg);

Comment: This is not related to the code in the question.

Comment: I found the reason is there was s syntax ' in the insert value,So how to insert a string including special character, like ' in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by change the command,Don't pass in parameters to queries using string concatenation, format, %, etc;

```
char * sql2 = "insert into t_elementnode(opname,op,param) values(?,?,?)";
if(elementNode.opname) sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, elementNode.opname.UTF8String, -1, NULL);
if(elementNode.op) sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, elementNode.op.UTF8String, -1, NULL);
if(elementNode.param) sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, elementNode.param.UTF8String, -1, NULL);
```